# Elements in different routes are inaccessible in a JavaScript single page application

Tags: javascript, html, routes, single-page-application

I have a route `"/login"` which has 2 input fields for `email` and `password`, and also there's a button to click after filling up the fields, however, I have to add an event listener for the fields if there's an `Enter Keypress` because I want the user to send the data by pressing enter rather than mouse click manually on the button, and I don't want to use `forms`.

Now, when I add that event listener in the home page as shown below, it says `element is null` since it cannot see it because it still didn't load the content of `"/login"` to the home page.

Any way to access those elements in different `routes`?

Here's the code for the **index page** `"/"`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vanilla SPA Router</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.5.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root">
        <nav id="main-nav" class="sidebar">
            <a href="/" onclick="route()">Home</a>
            <a href="/about" onclick="route()">About</a>
            <a href="/lorem" onclick="route()">Lorem</a>
            <a href="/login" onclick="route()">login</a>

        </nav>
        <div id="main-page"></div>
    </div>

<script> 
    // adding event listener here for id elements password
    var input = document.getElementById("password");

    input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
       if (event.key === "Enter") {
          event.preventDefault();
          document.getElementById("login_btn").click();
       }
    }); 

// the login() will be called by login_btn, but I didn't include 
// it for this question since it's unnecessary
</script>
    <script src="router.js"></script>
</body>
```

The code for the **login page** `"/login"` :

```
<input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email" />  
<input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" />
              
<button onClick="login()" id="login_btn" className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
```

**Javascript** code for routing:

```
const route = (event) => {
    event = event || window.event;
    event.preventDefault();
    window.history.pushState({}, "", event.target.href);
    handleLocation();
};

const routes = {
    404: "/pages/404.html",
    "/": "/pages/index.html",
    "/about": "/pages/about.html",
    "/lorem": "/pages/lorem.html",
    "/login": "/pages/login.html",

};

const handleLocation = async () => {
    const path = window.location.pathname;
    const route = routes[path] || routes[404];
    const html = await fetch(route).then((data) => data.text());
    document.getElementById("main-page").innerHTML = html;
};

window.onpopstate = handleLocation;
window.route = route;

handleLocation();
```

Comment: `adding event listener here for id elements password` can't you put that code in `The code for the login page` instead?

Comment: @JaromandaX I did add the code in the login.html page, but nothing happens, not sure why

Comment: oh, yeah, because you don't know how to correctly load `<script>` tags dynamically - alternative is to `document.addEventListener('keypress'` and test the id of the events target Element to see if it's the password input

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all self-closing HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to `keypress` on `document` - then check the ID of the target element

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.target?.id === 'password') {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      event.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById("login_btn").click();
    }
  }
});
```

Simple demo

```js
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.target?.id === 'password') {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("Enter pressed in password")
    }
  }
});
```

```html
Username: <input id="username"/><br/>
Password: <input id="password"/><br/>
```